# Why liquibase databasechangelog does not have primary key?

Tags: liquibase

I have start using [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) for database migrations and I have noticed that the table responsible for migrations(`databasechangelog`) does not has `primary key`.
I would like to know what is the logic behind such decision. I can not give myself reasonable answer so if someone know it I would apreciate to hear it.

Comment: http://forum.liquibase.org/#Topic/49382000001358015

Comment: I could accept your answer (even if the forum post didn't really answered question) so post it as an answer to accept it. "and there are some databases that have max key sizes larger than the author + id + filename values can be." is an answer that is very provisional. I expect that those mentioned fields are promoted to be unique and aside new autoincrement id could be introduced. Each time I open this table in pgadmin I am receiving warning that there is no primary key. It would be no surpsise that some databases will not allow table without PK.

Answer (score 0):

Statement from the liquibase bug tracker:

> We don't need a primary key by default because liquibase just does a
>   "select * from databasechangelog" to get everything back, so an index
>   isn't really going to help.

For more information see https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1909

Other related links:

- [Primary key required on DatabaseChangeLog table on Azure SQL](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2086)
- [Why does databasechangelog not have a primary key?](http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/why-does-databasechangelog-not-have-a-primary-key)